# Is it considered bad practice to repeatedly store identical rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm currently designing a database for an application which will be reading data from sensors every hour. Part of this data will be composed of readings. Storing them will not be a problem since they'll likely change every hour. The problem I have is that I also need to store settings data which is unlikely to change often. I'm wondering what best practice would be in this case. I was thinking I could store them in a separate table and add a datetime field. My program would then compare its hourly readings to the most recent database entry and only store them if something has changed. This would avoid repeatedly storing identical rows. Does it sound like a good idea or is this considered bad practice? Should I instead just store everything hourly?

Comment: Knowing nothinig about the business requirements of your app, I would say storing them every hour is SAFE (and disk space is cheap nowadays). Adding extra logic on top of it to store based on conditons gets tricky, unless you have event driven app when you have clear triggers of the changes. I would go for option #1 (store them every time). I prefer to sleep well at night.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! My app will only be using the sensor readings, really. It's storing the settings just in case they are needed in the future. You do make a point though, things would be simpler and space is cheap

Comment: Instrument data is often post-processed, and that activity could compress rows as well as apply calibration corrections and perform other cleanup steps.  Storing all of the original data is likely to be valuable if your workflow includes such a post-processing step.  In addition, if you have sensor identification information, sensor calibration data, or sensor installation data, that information is probably best stored in a separate table.

Comment: It also depends on whether the readings data comes from a different interface/API than the config data. Normally you would [normalise](https://www.sqlshack.com/what-is-database-normalization-in-sql-server/) your database. But as commented above sometimes its more practical not to. Depends also on how the data is used down the line.

Comment: The data is all coming from the same API in a JSON string. I have created separate tables for readings and settings to keep the database's format similar to the JSON's.

Comment: In staging table we do store everything